# I'm an ex-intern and I have a friend I want to recommend for my position

Tags: internship, references, replacement

I recently declined a part-time return offer for my internship.

However, I have a friend who is looking for a Summer job. He doesn't have the same technical skills as me but is very clever and would be able to pick it up.

The fact that I was offered a part-time position indicates that there would be work for him to do.

What's the appropriate way to recommend him to my boss? We're going out for lunch later this week with the rest of the team; would that be a good time to bring it up? Or would it be better as a thing I just go to his office about and bring up 1-on-1 in a more formal way?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely do this one-on-one.

As far as how to bring it up, say something along these lines:

> As you know, I can't stay on. Assuming that there's more work to be done in the future, and that you will soon be looking for a replacement for me, I would like, with your permission, to recommend a friend of mine for the position. *(he might say something at this point, but assuming he allows you to continue)* He doesn't quite have the same experience as me, but he's a very dedicated person, and very quick on the uptake. I honestly think he would be a good fit here if you were to give him a shot at an interview.

After that the ball is in their court.

Answer (score 0):

First question is if that is typical lunch, or he can expect that you have kind of interest in visiting. Think about it from his perspective.

I would talk about the company, how the team looks, what is going well, what is not. I would say something that I feel a bit guilty about not extending. On one hand that is only business, but also there is some trust in-between people. We all are human beings, and we can't run away from that - so that a bit of guilt... Then I could move to proposal, saying something about win-win case.

That can work if he knows that you care. So be honest - that is why I've wrote what I would do. Be honest explain why you think it is good option, how you see the situation - and that's it.

And yes one-on-one starting with him, not with a any one from the team.